# Adding More Javascript = Stops From Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery(function($) {
    function fixDiv() {
      var $cache = $('header'); 
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 10) 
        $cache.css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0', 'background': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)', 'padding': '0'}); 

        //$('#top-menu a').css({'padding': '17px 20px'});
      else
        $cache.css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': '0', 'background': 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', 'padding': '20px 0'});
        //$('#top-menu a').css({'padding': '30px 20px'});
    }
    $(window).scroll(fixDiv);
    fixDiv();
});
```

This is currently what I have, and i see var $cache = header so I wanted to add another line so when it changes the background it also changes the font size of the header.. so I now have

```
jQuery(function($) {
    function fixDiv() {
      var $cache = $('header'); 
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 10) 
        $cache.css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0', 'background': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)', 'padding': '0'}); 
       $('h1').css({'font-size': '26px'});
      else
        $cache.css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': '0', 'background': 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', 'padding': '20px 0'});
        $('h1').css({'font-size': '36px'});
    }
    $(window).scroll(fixDiv);
    fixDiv();
});
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do this for? `var $cache = $('header')`. Are you new to jQuery?

Comment: @incognito I was helped with this example and that was the way it was presented.. I don't know enough jQuery to know when to or when not to use vars so I left it that way

Comment: Can you post some HTML? I doubt you're trying to select all html tags called `<header>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple statements require braces:

```
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 10) 
  {
    $cache.css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0', 'background': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)', 'padding': '0'}); 
    $('h1').css({'font-size': '26px'});
  }
  else
  {
    $cache.css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': '0', 'background': 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', 'padding': '20px 0'});
    $('h1').css({'font-size': '36px'});
  }
```

Indenting your code properly makes it more obvious why it wasn't working:

```
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 10) 
     $cache.css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0', 'background': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)', 'padding': '0'}); 
  $('h1').css({'font-size': '26px'});
  else
     $cache.css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': '0', 'background': 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', 'padding': '20px 0'});
  $('h1').css({'font-size': '36px'});
```

(not only wrong but invalid - the `else` is orphaned).

Comment: Well, it's not part of any `if` statement.